# How to Produce Italicized Small Caps Using fontspec and the Code Compiled with Lualatex

Tags: luatex, italic, small-caps, lettrine, lmodern

I would like to obtain italicized small caps immediately following the lettrine. And so, I call in the `lmodern` and `slantsc` packages for this purpose into the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lettrine}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{slantsc}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\input GoudyIn.fd
\newcommand*\initfamily{\usefont{U}{GoudyIn}{xl}{n}}
\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\initfamily{}}
\setcounter{DefaultLines}{3}
\renewcommand{\DefaultLoversize}{.47}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\Large

\lettrine[lines=3,loversize=.25]{\initfamily{T}}{\textsl{he}} \textit{present little work is entitled ``A Book.''}
\end{document}
```

which produces, unfortunately, not what I want:

[image]

Notice that the letters immediately following the lettrine are italicized but not in small caps.

However, when I comment out `\usepackage{fontspec}` and run the code with `lualatex`, I get what I am looking for:

[image]

Now, in the document I am working on, I need the `fontspec` package and I must compile it with `lualatex`.

*Remark:* I can produce straight small-caps with `fontspec` and `lualatex` by ``` \lettrine[lines=3,loversize=.25]{\initfamily{T}}{he} \textit{present little work is entitled ``A Book.''} ``` which produces:

[image]

QUESTION: How may the above code be modified so that I may produce italicized small caps for the letters immediately following the lettrine, with the `fontspec` package invoked, and the code compiled with `lualatex`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The font will be automatically chosen if you remove `\usepackage{lmodern}` and `\usepackage{slantsc}` which make no sense with `fontspec`.

You can even avoid the annoying font substitution warning.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{pdftexcmds}

\input{GoudyIn.fd}
\newcommand*\initfamily{\usefont{U}{GoudyIn}{xl}{n}}
\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\initfamily}
\setcounter{DefaultLines}{3}
\renewcommand{\DefaultLoversize}{.47}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\LettrineTextFont}{%
  \ifnum\pdf@strcmp{\f@shape}{it}=0 \slshape\fi
  \scshape
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lettrine[lines=3,loversize=.25]{T}{he} present little work is entitled ``A Book.''

\vspace{1cm}

\itshape
\lettrine[lines=3,loversize=.25]{T}{he} present little work is entitled ``A Book.''

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note also the changes I made to your code. It's not necessary to state `\initfamily` twice, for instance, and `\input` should be followed by a brace.

Comment: Thank you @egreg.

Answer (score 1):

You can’t combine legacy 8-bit font packages, such as `lmodern`, with `fontspec`. (Or you can, but it takes a lot of extra work.)

Load instead a font that contains italic small caps, such as New Computer Modern Book (although the default, Latin Modern, should just work these days), and you can use `\textsc{\textit{Foo}}` or `{\itshape\scshape Foo}`.

If you really, truly want to use an 8-bit text encoding and `fontspec` in the same document, you should invoke `\usefont` or `fontencoding` to switch the font encoding of the first word, e.g. `\usefont{T1}{lmr}{m}{scit}`.  You might want to load `fontaxes`, or a package such as `cfr-lm` that makes more of the options of 8-bit Latin Modern available.

Comment: There is no need to load newcomputermodern. In a current latex `\textsc{\textit{he}}`  should work. There is normally also no need to use fontaxes anymore as latex now contains that functionality.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Corrected. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{libertinus}
\input GoudyIn.fd
\newcommand*\initfamily{\usefont{U}{GoudyIn}{xl}{n}}
\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\initfamily{}}
\setcounter{DefaultLines}{3}
\renewcommand{\DefaultLoversize}{.47}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\Large
\lettrine[lines=3,loversize=.25]{\initfamily{T}}{\textit{he}} \textit{present little work is 
entitled ``A Book.''}
\end{document}
```

[image]